# Customized Message Box in Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, messagebox, messagedialog

I am not very much familiar with windows phone programming.

I need a message box like this

[image]

I have figured out how to show simple message box. Mean I can show a title (Alert), Desc (Account number is required), and a OK button.

And now I don't know how to:

1. Change the color to `Alert` text.
2. Its background to that dark color.
3. And button background to orange color.

Well by using toolkit described in [this link](http://www.windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox-in-windows-phone-application-3/) I would be able to change the color of Alert text. But I don't to use a whole toolkit just to change the color or that text. But if it can customize my message box as in above picture than I would definitely use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [`ContentDialog` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx). It will let you put whatever you want into a dialog.